# how to upload files to s3 public bucket without credentials form client side javascript

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services

We'd like to use Javascript AWS SDK to upload files to S3, but without using credentials at all. Uploading using credentials works

We have a bucket which has the permissions of  anyone that can upload and download files when i am trying to upload i'm getting this error

```
message: "No credentials to load"
```

**mycode :**

```
var bucket = new AWS.S3({params: {Bucket: 'bucketName'}});

 var params = {Key: 'data.txt', Body: "kkkkkkkkkkkk"};

bucket.putObject(params, function (err, data) {
alert(err)

});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have set read/write permissions for all users and your bucket's cors configuration allows PUT requests you should be able to simply do it with ajax:

```
function httpReq(method, url, data, successCB, errorCB) {
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

    xhr.addEventListener('load', function () {
        if (xhr.status == 200) {
            successCB(xhr.response);
        } else {
            errorCB({status: xhr.status, response: xhr.response});
        }
    });

    xhr.open(method, url, true);
    xhr.send(data);
}

httpReq('PUT', 'http://yourBucket.s3.amazonaws.com/yourKey', file, function (response) {
    console.log('Upload Successful', response);
}, function (error) {
    console.error(error);
});
```