# python upload to S3 without credentials

Tags: python-2.7, amazon-s3, boto3, boto

I have S3 bucket which has following policy to allow full access from specific IP

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "PublicWriteFromIP",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:*",
            "Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::logs-dev",
                "arn:aws:s3:::logs-dev/*"
            ],
            "Condition": {
                "IpAddress": {
                    "aws:SourceIp": "#.#.#.#/32"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I want to upload file to S3 bucket without any credentials using python. When I tried to use boto/boto3 with empty env `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=''` & `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=''` I got following error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 209, in bucket_upload_file
    ExtraArgs=ExtraArgs, Callback=Callback, Config=Config)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/inject.py", line 131, in upload_file
    extra_args=ExtraArgs, callback=Callback)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/boto3/s3/transfer.py", line 279, in upload_file
    future.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 106, in result
    return self._coordinator.result()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/s3transfer/futures.py", line 265, in result
    raise self._exception
botocore.exceptions.NoCredentialsError: Unable to locate credentials
```

How can I upload files to S3 bucket without credentials ? Is it possible to just use `urllib2` to upload file to S3 (public) ?

Comment: maybe it can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25722419/how-to-upload-files-to-s3-public-bucket-without-credentials-form-client-side-jav

Answer (score 0):

I had to **enable** `Static Web hosting` & set `Block all public access` to **off**

Then following code worked

```
import requests
url = "https://logs-dev.s3-us-east-1.amazonaws.com/"
data = { 'key': '/test.txt' }
files = { 'file': open('/tmp/test.txt', 'rb') }
r = requests.post(url, data=data, files=files)
print "status %s" % r.status_code
```